# C# sql update query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to use this to `update` the `note column in sql table`

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    SqlConnection connorder = new SqlConnection("Data Source=P4\\WORK;Initial Catalog=Agenda_X1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxx");
    connorder.Open();

    string ordernrsql = lbOrderNr.Text;
    string newstate = lbNewState.Text;

    SqlCommand commandorder = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Agenda_X1].[dbo].[Order] SET Note = @lbNewState WHERE OrderNr= @ordernumber", connorder);
    commandorder.Parameters.Add("@ordernumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ordernrsql;
    commandorder.Parameters.Add("@lbNewState", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newstate;
    connorder.Close();
}
```

In VS FR - SQL Commnad Visualizer looks like this

```
`DECLARE @ordernumber NVarChar;
SET @ordernumber = 'OPT1710420';
DECLARE @lbNewState NVarChar;
SET @lbNewState = 'Order changed 2017.06.02';

UPDATE [SAgenda_X1].[dbo].[Objednavky_ObjednavkaPrijata] SET Note= @lbNewState WHERE OrderNr = @ordernumber
```

But in sql this didn`t work and should be like this:

```
`DECLARE @ordernumber NVarChar (max);
    SET @ordernumber = 'OPT1710420';
    DECLARE @lbNewState NVarChar (max);
    SET @lbNewState = 'Order changed 2017.06.02';

    UPDATE [SAgenda_X1].[dbo].[Objednavky_ObjednavkaPrijata] SET Note= @lbNewState WHERE OrderNr = @ordernumber
```

also would like ask you what should i do that the finally sql query will be already with `NVarChar (max)`??

i already try

```
commandorder.Parameters.Add("@ordernumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = ordernrsql;
commandorder.Parameters.Add("@lbNewState", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = newstate;
```

but still sql without change.

Comment: in one query you have `SAgenda_X1` and in other you have `Agenda_X1` as Database name. Have you tried with only schema and table name, like `UPDATE [dbo].[Order] SET Note`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute the Command like `commandorder.ExecuteNonQuery();`

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    SqlConnection connorder = new SqlConnection("Data Source=P4\\WORK;Initial Catalog=Agenda_X1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxx");
    connorder.Open();

    string ordernrsql = lbOrderNr.Text;
    string newstate = lbNewState.Text;

    SqlCommand commandorder = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Agenda_X1].[dbo].[Order] SET Note = @lbNewState WHERE OrderNr= @ordernumber", connorder);
    commandorder.Parameters.Add("@ordernumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ordernrsql;
    commandorder.Parameters.Add("@lbNewState", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newstate;

    commandorder.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connorder.Close();
}
```